# Xcode 10 Generics typealias Segmentation Fault 11 while archiving

Tags: ios, swift, generics, xcode10, type-alias

Segmentation Fault while **archiving** on **Xcode 10**

Note:

- Xcode 10 **build** and **run** on devices and simulator working fine 
  and  in Xcode 9.4 also **archiving**, **build**, and **run** working fine

My code:

```
typealias ResponseBlock<T> = (_ sender: T) -> Void
```

I am using this in all over the project like:

```
var callback: ResponseBlock<AnyObject>?
```

**Error while archiving on Xcode 10:**

2. While generating Objective-C header
3. While printing ................
4. While printing type 'ResponseBlock<[IndexPath]>' (declared at.....] RangeText="typealias ResponseBlock = (_ sender: T) -> V")
5. While printing type '(T)'
   **error: Segmentation fault: 11**

Usage:

```
var refreshCells: ResponseBlock<[IndexPath]>?
viewModel.refreshCells = {indexPathList in 
     self.collectionView.reloadItems(at:   indexPathList)
}
```

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: @kubacizek please check my answer hope it will solve your issue as well

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed  XCODE 10 Archive is on release mode and build, run is on Debug mode.

So I checked the difference between **Release** and **Debug** mode configuration

**Findings:**
 [image]

**Solution:** 
[image]

It Solved my problem, now no longer receiving Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Build system to use the legacy build system worked for me:

**File > Workspace Settings**

[image: Setting build system]